Was there an episode which showed the Monty Hall Problem?
There is a math problem named Monty Hall Problem.

Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?

from 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem
So, was there an episode which contained such a deal?
If there are several such episodes, then it is better to find an episode with such constraints:

The host must always open a door that was not picked by the contestant 
The host must always open a door to reveal a goat and never the car.
The host must always offer the chance to switch between the originally chosen door and the remaining closed door.

As I understand, such episode should be aired somewhere in 1990 of before as the problem appeared in 1990 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem#CITEREFvos_Savant1990a

Are you asking if there's an episode where they specifically mentioned the math problem named "The Monty Hall Problem?" Or are you asking which episodes showed the problem in action? If the latter, it's pretty much all episodes, as that's how the game was played.
